# $lookup for id inside array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have some models that look like this:

```
const exerciseDetailSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        Translations: {
            Name: {
                en: { type: String, required: true },
                no: { type: String }
            }
        }
    }
);

const workoutDetailSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        Sets: {
            Exercises: [ WorkoutExercises ],
            Units: { type: String }
        }
    }
);

const WorkoutSets = new mongoose.Schema({
    Reps: { type: Number },
    Weight: { type: Number }
});

const WorkoutExercises = new mongoose.Schema({
    ExerciseId: { type: String, required: true },
    Sets: [ WorkoutSets ]
});
```

Basically, workouts are made of Sets, which contain some metadata including exercises. These exercises is an array which is made of workout sets.

I am trying to make a query that will return to me the Workout Details including the Exercise Name, so that it can look like this:

```
{
   _id: "5f60dc1069c27c015ede4e3e",
   Sets: {
      Units: 'metric',
      Exercises: [
         {
            _id: "5f60dc1069c27c015ede4e3e",
            ExerciseId: "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf414",
            ExerciseName: {
               en: "Squat",
               no: "Knebøy"
            },
            Sets: [
               { _id: "5f60dc1069c27c015ede4e3f", Reps: 10 },
               { _id: "5f60dc1069c27c015ede4e40", Reps: 20 }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This would be with an example exercise like:

```
{
   _id: "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf414",
   Translations: {
      Name: {
         en: "Squat",
         no: "Knebøy"
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried using a $lookup, like this:

```
const workout = await WorkoutDetail.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: ExerciseDetail.collection.name,
                localField: "Sets.Exercises.ExerciseId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "ExerciseDetail"
            }
        }
]);
```

But it is always returning with just: `ExerciseDetail: []` for the part that is supposed to be "joined". Can anyone provide any help with how to query this properly?

### UPDATE

I have asked in another question here about grouping this data, and received an answer that had done it perfectly. Hopefully it can be helpful to others also:
[MongoDB $group (mongo playground)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908926/mongodb-group-mongo-playground)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Exercises` is an array, you need to `$unwind` to flat the array.

```
[
  {
    $unwind: "$Sets.Exercises"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "exerciseDetailSchema",
      localField: "Sets.Exercises.ExerciseId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "ExerciseDetail"
    }
  }
]
```

Note : To restructure you need to use `$group`. I've not shown since you had a problem with `lookup`

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pdsfjl2SdEu)

Comment: Thanks for the info on the $unwind, and the mongo playground and $group. I have been trying with this for a little while now, and am facing some issues with the proper grouping. Would you have an idea setting this up right? I have a link here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/GVQo0LoJd_6

Comment: I basically just need to get each ExerciseDetail into the Set object, but cannot find the proper setup for doing that

Comment: @RidgeRobinson I'm sorry for the late reply, I think you got the answer. If there anything feel free to contact me