# MongoDB $group (mongo playground)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906930/lookup-for-id-inside-array-of-objects) about the $unwind operator, but am facing issues with grouping the data properly after.

I have a [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GVQo0LoJd_6) with an example, but here it is also. After an `$unwind`, `$lookup` and `$group` in the query (maybe there is a better, more efficient way to do it?), I am left with this data:

```
[
  {
    "ExerciseDetail": [
      [{ "Name": "Squat", "_id": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf414" }],
      [{ "Name": "Deadlift", "_id": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf415" }]
    ],
    "Sets": [
      {
        "ExerciseId": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf414",
        "Sets": [],
        "WorkoutExerciseId": "5f60dc1069c27c015ede4e3e"
      },
      {
        "ExerciseId": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf415",
        "Sets": [],
        "WorkoutExerciseId": "5f60dc1069c27c015ede4e34"
      }
    ],
    "_id": "5f60dc1069c27c015ede4e3e"
  }
]
```

What I want to do though, it to have each of the Exercise Detail objects, be added to the respective Sets object, based on the equivalent ExerciseId, so that the final result would look like:

```
{
     "_id": "5f60dc1069c27c015ede4e3e",
     "Sets": [
        {
           "ExerciseId": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf414",
           "Name": "Squat",
           "Sets": [],
           "WorkoutExerciseId": "5f60dc1069c27c015ede4e3e"
        },
        {
           "ExerciseId": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf415",
           "Name": "Deadlift",
           "Sets": [],
           "WorkoutExerciseId": "5f60dc1069c27c015ede4e34"
        }
     ]
}
```

Can anyone help with the proper grouping? (and if you see a better way to $unwind, $lookup also?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two additional stages. Firstly you can run [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to flatten `ExerciseDetail` which now is an array of arrays. Once it's done you can run [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) with nested [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to pair `Sets` with `ExerciseDetails`:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        ExerciseDetail: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$ExerciseDetail",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                    $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
},

{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        Sets: {
            $map: {
                input: "$Sets",
                as: "set",
                in: {
                    $let: {
                        vars: {
                            exDetail: {
                                $arrayElemAt: [
                                    { $filter: { input: "$ExerciseDetail", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$$set.ExerciseId" ] } } },
                                    0
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        in: {
                            $mergeObjects: [
                                "$$set", "$$exDetail"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C4Y-1Vc4eBv)

Comment: This looks perfect ... I am coming from a SQL world and just learning Mongo. This is seeming to be a lot of work for what equates to a fairly simple JOIN in sql. Regardless of the sql vs nosql argument, this has been very helpful example. Thanks!

Comment: @RidgeRobinson true, there's no such operator as join for arrays, I wish we had one